# Excel column values being appended as rows instead of columns into datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, epplus

I have an Excel file which I need to read through and extract particular values of a certain range into a datatable so I can then save that data into a table in a database.

Whilst debugging, on every loop I check the datatable visualizer to see what's going on and I find that I'm appending values of a different row, to the same row. Example in photo.

[SamplePhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h87tR.jpg)

Here is the code responsible for that action.(Surrounded in a Try-Catch)

```
Using excel As New ExcelPackage (ulTarget.PostedFile.InputStream)
Dim _worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First()
Dim _hasHeader = True

   For Each cell In _worksheet.Cells(1,2,147,4)
_dataTable.Columns.Add(If(_hasHeader, cell.Value, String.Format("{0}", cell.Start.Column)))
If _worksheet.Cells.Value Is Nothing Then
Continue For
Next
```

Assume that the range 1,2,147,4 is correct as the data going into the datatable is correct, the row seperation is simply the problem. _dataTable is my DataTable (obvious I know but nothing bad in clarifying it) and _hasHeader is set to True because the Excel worksheet being uploaded has headers and I don't want them being put into the DataTable because the data will all end up in a table in SQL Server where appropriate column names exist.

Also ulTarget is my File uploader. I am using EPPlus most recent version for this.

Anybody have any suggestions as to how I can seperate the data into rows as per the example in the photo above? Happy to make any clarifications if needed.

Comment: You haven't shown the start of the loop or where `cell` is initialised. Please make sure the question contains a [mcve]

Comment: I apologise! Thanks. Code updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the horizontal range of the columns without headers and read each cell row by row.

```
            Using excel As New ExcelPackage(ulTargetFile.PostedFile.InputStream)
                'Add the columns'
                Dim _worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First()
                Dim _hasHeader As Boolean = False
                For Each col In _worksheet.Cells("B1:D1")
                    _dataTable.Columns.Add(If(_hasHeader, Nothing, col.Value))
                    String.Format("{0}", col.Start.Column)
                Next
                'Add the rows'
                For rowNumber As Integer = 1 To 147
                    Dim worksheetRow = _worksheet.Cells(rowNumber, 2, rowNumber, 4)
                    Dim row As DataRow = _dataTable.Rows.Add()
                    For Each cell In worksheetRow
                        row(cell.Start.Column - 2) = cell.Value
                    Next
                Next
```